# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let be $V=\mathbb{R}^4$ with the standard scalar product, and $F:V\rightarrow V$ symmetric (its matrix representation satisfies $A^t=A$) and biunivocal and $F^3=F$ (so $F(F(F(v)))=F(v)$). The set of vectors $\vec{v} \in V$ such that $F(\vec{v})=\vec{v}$ is $$S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3.x_4) \:\:| \: x_1=x_2 ,\: x_3=x_4\}$$

Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $F$.

Can you give me a hint about how to start?

Comment: "Biunivocal" is not a commonly used term ("symmetric", on the other hand, is common).  Do you mean that $F^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: I mean that $F$ is injective and surjective

Comment: okay.  The more commonly used terms are "invertible" and "non-singular" in the context of matrices.  "Bijective" is also commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make the following observations:

- Since $F^3 = F$, we can multiply both sides by $F^{-1}$ to find that $F^2 = I$ (where $I$ denotes the identity matrix).
- The only eigenvalues $F$ can have are $1$ and $-1$.
- $S$ is the eigenspace of $F$ associated with $1$.
- Because $F$ is symmetric and our earlier statement about eigenvalues, the elements of $S^\perp$ must be eigenvectors associated with $-1$.

Comment: I follow you up to the second point, since the matrix representation of $F$ should be $$\begin{pmatrix} \pm1 &0&0&0 \\ 0&\pm1&0&0 \\ 0&0&\pm1&0 \\ 0&0&0&\pm1 \end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: Why vectors $(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1)$ (the span of $S$) are the eigenvectors associated with $1$? I don't know how many eigenvalues are $1$ or $-1$ so i can't find eigenvectors

Comment: Note that "$v$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda$" means that $F(v) = \lambda v$.  All elements of $S$ satisfy $F(v) = 1 \cdot v$

Comment: The vectors you found form a basis of $S$, so those are all the eigenvectors for $\lambda = 1$.  For the eigenvectors of $\lambda = -1$, you just need to find a basis of $S^\perp$

Comment: Wow, thanks. I got it.